# ipywidgets - display next value in list after clicking

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I'm trying to use `ipywidgets` in order to display next value in my list (in Jupyter notebook) given as `display_vals` after clicking the button. However, with the following code snippet, I got error as

```
local variable 'i' referenced before assignment
```

Here is the snippet that I have

```
from IPython.display import display, clear_output
import ipywidgets as widgets

button = widgets.Button(description="Click Me!")
display(button)

display_vals = ['a', 'b', 'c']
i = 0

def on_button_clicked(b):
    print(display_vals[i])
    clear_output()
    i += 1

button.on_click(on_button_clicked)
```

I guess I just don't know the way to parse my variable when button gets clicked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it by declaring i as a global and including an if statement like so:

```
from IPython.display import display, clear_output
import ipywidgets as widgets

button = widgets.Button(description="Click Me!")
display(button)

display_vals = ['a', 'b', 'c']
i = 0

def on_button_clicked(b):
    global i

    clear_output()
    if i < len(display_vals):
        print(display_vals[i])
        i += 1

button.on_click(on_button_clicked)
```

However you should rename `i` to be something a little bit more unique if you do decide to go this route.